# Как получить адрес страницы без протокола?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, protocol

Как получить адрес страницы без `http(s)://` ? Есть ли какой нибудь метод? Или только `Trim`-ом?

Comment: http://javascript.ru/window-location

Comment: Уже смотрел. Вопрос остаёются тем же

Comment: @Sergey это сарказм или решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let location = window.location;
location.host + location.pathname + location.hash`?

Answer (score 3):

Можно регулярным выражением отсечь:

```
url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com";
url = url.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "");
```